# CentOS 6.4 : Cannot login as root ssh anymore

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

When I enter the password it gives me the following error:

```
login: root 
Password: My-password
Login incorrect
```

I have tried SSH via Putty as well as WinSCP. I get Network Error: Connection refused.

So what could have gone wrong?

Please advise.

Please Note: root is not the only user on this machine, I can access with another account and perform some command .

I tried to reset the root  password following the instructions on some other site. All went well, except I get the same error despite changing the password!

The last major thing I did was : create user , create group , associate the user to the group created and than change folder dir to the user inside etc/passwd.
After that I start to have the root problem , so i cancel the user and the group created but i still facing the same problem

Comment: Since you can login as another user, you've looked at the logs haven't you?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us some logs about sshd to see what happens from inside /var/log directory.
just run `# grep sshd * | grep the_number_of_the_date_that_you_want_to_check` or you can run this `grep -Ri ssh /var/log/*`

Also:
1. Do you have a line in your **sshd_config** that refers to "**AllowUsers**"? (most dont but some do, and if yours does, you need your account listed on that line).
2. Do you have iptables allowing **TCP 22**? 
3. The service i hope is started :) (`# service sshd status`) 
4. Last but not least: is `PermitRootLogin yes` in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

Comment: UPDATE useful for beginner like me :

This issue happen because customer edited the /etc/passwd from a Window environment.
Noticed /etc/passwd file had DOS line endings.

For example when we use vi editor to open /etc/passwd file following were noticed :

vi /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash^M
The ^M should not be there and is likely introduced by editing on a Windows platform (although there could be other explanations).

In order to fix the issue remove ^M at the end of each line in /etc/passwd file.

Solution found on [https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/258803]